# Django custom Management: Unable for an "administrator" to update an user

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm currently creating a django customer management/admin interface for a web application(I know of the built-in one, but as part of this project, a custom one needs to be created).
I'm supposed to be able to create/update/delete users from this interface, while connected as a Manager/Admin.
While connected as a manager/admin I can successfully create or delete an user, I'm unable to update one (I keep getting the error that the user "already exists")
Help or the wright direction to follow would be much apreciated as I've been struging with this for a while and am blocked atm.

Hereunder the code.

***(models.py) class UserProfile (one to one to built-in Django User class)***

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    """
    The Class UserProfile extends the built-in "User" class of Django
    Used here to add extra fields in the forms 
    """
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="User")
    vpn_enabled = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="VPN Enabled")
    language = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=LANGUAGES, default='EN', verbose_name="Language")
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True, verbose_name="Birth Date")
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Address")
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Postal Code")
    country = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Country")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'User Profile'
        verbose_name_plural = 'User Profiles'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

***views.py***

```
@group_required('Administrator', 'Manager')
def update_user(request, id):  
    user = User.objects.get(id=id)  
    user_update_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST or None, instance = user) 
    user_profile_update_form =  UserProfileUpdateForm (request.POST or None, instance = user.userprofile) 
    if user_update_form.is_valid() and user_profile_update_form.is_valid(): 
        user_update_form.save()  
        user_profile_update_form.save()
        return redirect("manager_home")  
    
    context = {
        'user_update_form': user_update_form,
        'user_profile_update_form': user_profile_update_form,
    }    
    return render (request, "update_user.html", context)
```

***forms.py***

```
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """UserUpdateForm custom made class"""

    class Meta:
        """ Meta definitioon of UserUpdateForm"""

        model = User
        fields = [
            'username',
            'last_name',
            'first_name',
            'email',
        ]

class UserProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    '''UserProfileUpdateForm custom made class'''

    class Meta:
        """Meta definition of UserProfileUpdateForm"""

        model = UserProfile
        fields = [
            'language',
            'birth_date',
            'address',
            'postal_code',
            'country',
        ]
```

***template***

```
<!-- template update_user.html -->
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %} Edit User {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<form method="POST" class="post-form" action="{% url 'update_user' user.id %}"> 
{% csrf_token %}  
{{user_update_form.as_p}}
{{user_profile_update_form.as_p}}
{{user_update_form.errors}}
<hr>
<button type="submit">Update User</button>
</form>
{% endblock  %}
```

***result (while trying to update, for example, user country)***
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHuVY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the view. If you are using function as a view you need to say explicitly what you do in case of the post request, otherwise everything will be processed as GET request, and this is not something that you want.

```
@group_required('Administrator', 'Manager')
def update_user(request, id):  
    if request.method == 'GET':
        # get request processing code
    # you are missing POST request processing part
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # post request processing code
```

Comment: Indeed, it solved my problem. Thanks a lot